# Trigger jquery script from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I am trying to do the following:

1: Load an XML file (with a list devices that has a static name, and a changing value and note) - this works

2: Load the XML (t=0) into varaiables for easy use in the HTML - this works

3: Load XML again (t=200ms) - this works (I think)

4: Check if any values have changed between the two XML's

5: If TRUE then update one or more `<DIV id=>`

Task 1: I guess I need to have the loadxml script run again whenever it is done or say every 200 ms
Task 2: I need to write and call a script that can update the `<DIV id=>`

I have made my code with only two parameters for easy understanding and put in comments where I guess I need to have something.

If this is a crazy overall architecture, please give me a direction to look to.

```
<?php

loadxml() ;

function loadxml() {
$feed_url = "demoxml.xml";
$xml = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);

for ($id=1; $id<=157; $id++) {

//dynamic
$generation='new';
$hs3device_note[$id][$generation]= $array['device'][$id]['@attributes']['note'] ;
if ($hs3device_note[$id]['current'] != $hs3device_note[$id]['new']) { ;
$hs3device_note[$id]['current'] = $hs3device_note[$id]['new'] ;
//CALL SCRIPT (like ReplaceContentInContainer) TO UPDATE <DIV id = $id> WITH CONTENT $hs3device_note[$id]['new']) 
} ;
$hs3device_value[$id][$generation]= $array['device'][$id]['@attributes']['value'] ;
if ($hs3device_value[$id]['current'] != $hs3device_value[$id]['new']) { ;
$hs3device_value[$id]['current'] = $hs3device_value[$id]['new'] ;
//CALL SCRIPT (like ReplaceContentInContainer) TO UPDATE <DIV id = $id> WITH CONTENT $hs3device_note[$id]['new']) 
} ;

}
//MAKE loadxml() call it self or restart in 200 ms
} ;

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.2.js'>
function ReplaceContentInContainer() {
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
</script>

<DIV id="hs3device_note[34]['current']">...</DIV> 
<DIV id="hs3device_value[34]['current']">...</DIV>
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is AJAX.

Comment: @Edward - im not sure yet, im trying to play around with it. I can get the json/xml to load into the array, from here I need to do some conditional formatting before updating the div's - but I cant find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

AJAX or Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is a method of sending requests to a server from JavaScript asynchronously (hence the name), with your question it would mean you can send a request to the server (at a specified interval) to see if some data has changed and if the PHP script evaluates true (ie it has) then it is sent back to the HTML page to replace the existing data that is being displayed.

```
function myXMLRequest() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "script.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { action:'testmyxml' },
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            myXMLRequest();
        }, 5000);
        if(msg != "") {
            $( "#mydiv" ).html( msg );
        }
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    myXMLRequest();
});
```

Reference: JQuery API documentation.

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

the `script.php` is your php script that does all the logic, data is sent back using PHP's 'echo' command, if not don't echo anything... (you can test if `msg` is empty client side). `msg` will hold all the information that has been echoed by PHP in `script.php` and can be put into a div as shown in my example.